Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/annotation/ImportCandidates
when I start the spring boot application, shows error like this:
2024-10-15 23:21:29.447  WARN 23829 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/retire/dolphin-common-biz/build/libs/dolphin-common-biz-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar!/exception/feign/FeignClientErrorDecoder.class]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/annotation/ImportCandidates
2024-10-15 23:21:29.586 ERROR 23829 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/retire/dolphin-common-biz/build/libs/dolphin-common-biz-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar!/exception/feign/FeignClientErrorDecoder.class]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/annotation/ImportCandidates
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:457) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:316) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:276) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:128) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:296) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:207) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:175) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at com.dolphin.server.FeignServerApplication.main(FeignServerApplication.java:21) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/annotation/ImportCandidates
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationExcludeFilter.getAutoConfigurations(AutoConfigurationExcludeFilter.java:69) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.18.jar:2.7.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationExcludeFilter.isAutoConfiguration(AutoConfigurationExcludeFilter.java:62) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.18.jar:2.7.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationExcludeFilter.match(AutoConfigurationExcludeFilter.java:51) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.18.jar:2.7.18]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.isCandidateComponent(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:489) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:430) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.annotation.ImportCandidates
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    ... 25 common frames omitted

this is the gradle config of the version:
project(":dolphin-feign:dolphin-feign-service") {
    archivesBaseName = "dolphin-feign-service"
    version = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
    bootJar {
        manifest {
            attributes 'Start-Class': 'com.dolphin.gateway.GatewayApplication'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
        implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign"
        implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer")
        api project(":dolphin-feign:dolphin-feign-api")
        compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.34'
        annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.34'

        testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.34'
        testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.34'
        implementation 'cn.hutool:hutool-all:5.8.25'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.7.18'
    }
}

project(":dolphin-feign") {
    dependencies {
    }
}

project(":dolphin-feign:dolphin-feign-api") {
    jar {
        enabled = true
    }

    bootJar {
        enabled = false
    }

    dependencies {
        api project(":dolphin-common-biz")
    }
}

I have tried to upgrade spring boot to 3.3.4, but still did not fixed this issue. what should I do to fixed this problem?
